# Searchable label text Chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm trying to get the label text within my Chartjs Bar chart's to be discoverable via a normal ctrl+F or cmd+F search. I'm not really sure how to approach this, as it seems that the text generated within the canvas isn't rendered as text within HTML elements.

Comment: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1976

Answer (score 2):

Chartjs uses HTML5 canvas to create it's graphics. The HTML 5 canvas, by design, is a drawing board, so any text inside the canvas is considered a drawing, therefore, not searchable, unfortunately.